# Refactoring a large union statement to use a SELECT which breaks early

Tags: mysql, sql

It's a bit difficult to explain the situation, but currently I'm generating *massive* unions to accomplish this. They look at bit like:

```
(
    SELECT
        ipaddress
    FROM post
    WHERE ipaddress = 'someipaddress'
        AND userid NOT IN (1, {$postinfo['userid']}, {$vbulletin->options['sdwikipostuserid']})
    LIMIT 1
)
UNION
(
    SELECT
        ipaddress
    FROM post
    WHERE ipaddress = 'someotheripaddress'
        AND userid NOT IN (1, {$postinfo['userid']}, {$vbulletin->options['sdwikipostuserid']})
    LIMIT 1
)
```

These get huge fast, but seem to be the fastest way for me to accomplish this right now. I've tried refactoring it to something like:

```
SELECT
    ipaddress
FROM post
WHERE ipaddress in ('all ips', .....)
    AND userid NOT IN (1, {$postinfo['userid']}, {$vbulletin->options['sdwikipostuserid']})
GROUP BY ipaddress
```

But this is around x5 **slower** than the massive union statement. The big issue is that the post table is huuuuuge, so the refactored SQL is forced to look through the entire table where each union statement can break after finding a single instance. Is there any way to specify the SQL to break on finding the first unique group?

Anyone have tips on how to refactor the huge union statement above into something cleaner?

Comment: Do you have an index on `post(ipaddress, userid)`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes, both are indexed

Comment: . . One index with two columns. not two.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the query like this:

```
select i.ipaddress
from (select 'someipaddress' as ipaddress union all
      select 'someotheripaddress'
     ) i
where exists (select 1
              from posts p
              where p.ipaddress = i.ipaddress and
                    p.userid NOT IN (1, {$postinfo['userid']}, {$vbulletin->options['sdwikipostuserid']})
             );
```

This is optimized with an index on `posts(ipaddress, userid)` -- one index, two columns.